# How to get exit code from the expect/spawn command in unix

Tags: expect, spawn

Based on one of the topics posted here, i have designed my expect script to return the exit code but for some reason it keeps on running and doesnt exit at all

I am using the below script to
-get a file from the remote server
-delete the file after the transfer is complete

Below is the code written

```
set timeout 30

set user [lindex $argv 0]
set pass [lindex $argv 1]
set host [lindex $argv 2]
set remote_file [lindex $argv 3]
set local_file [lindex $argv 4]
set port [lindex $argv 5]

if {$port != "" } {
spawn sftp -oPort=$port $user@$host
} else {
spawn sftp $user@$host}
expect -nocase password:
send "$pass\r"
expect sftp>

send "get $local_file $remote_file\r"
expect sftp>

send "rm $local_file\r"
expect eof

set waitval [wait -i $spawn_id]
exit [lindex $waitval 3]
```

-> It should have exit with the return code.

I am using the below alternate script for now. It works. But I was hoping to make it more generic without mentioning the error messages. Please let me know if there is any improvements that can be done for the below script.

```
set timeout 30

set user [lindex $argv 0]
set pass [lindex $argv 1]
set host [lindex $argv 2]
set remote_file [lindex $argv 3]
set local_file [lindex $argv 4]
set port [lindex $argv 5]

if {$port != "" } {
spawn sftp -oPort=$port $user@$host
} else {
spawn sftp $user@$host}
expect -nocase password:
send "$pass\r"
expect {
-re "failed|invalid password|incorrect|denied" {exit 1}
"Connection closed" {exit 1}
timeout {exit 1}
"sftp>"
}

send "get $local_file $remote_file\r"
expect {
-re "not found|denied|error|failure" {exit 1}
"No such file or directory" {exit 1}
timeout {exit 1}
"sftp>"
}

send "rm $local_file\r"
expect {
-re "not found|denied|cannot remove|error|failure" {exit 1}
"No such file or directory" {exit 1}
"sftp>"
}

send "exit\r"
expect eof
```

Regards,
Allen

Comment: Code reviews belong on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ -- my first reaction is "fix your indentation"

Answer (score 2):

For your first script:

> It should have exit with the return code.

You need to *tell* the spawned `sftp` to exit, else `wait` waits forever:

```
[...]
send "get $local_file $remote_file\r"
expect sftp>

send "rm $local_file\r"
expect sftp>

send "exit\r"

set waitval [wait -i $spawn_id]
exit [lindex $waitval 3]
```

As for the second script, I'd at minimum define a `proc` that gracefully exits on an error condition, instead of just `exit 1` with no explanation. Something like this:

```
# Lets user know what went wrong, then gracefully stop sftp
proc err_exit {msg} {
  puts stderr "ERROR: $msg, aborting."
  send "exit\r"
  expect eof
  exit 1
}
[...]
expect {
  -re "failed|invalid password|incorrect|denied" {
    err_exit "Access denied"
  }
  "Connection closed" {
    err_exit "sftp connection closed unexpectedly"
  }
  timeout {
    err_exit "Timeout occurred"
  }
  "sftp>"
}
```

Oh, and your code is in serious need of proper indentation and alignment. Tcl doesn't care, but code comprehension is hampered without it. (Take the fact that you told `sftp` to exit in the second script but not the first as a warning sign.)

Answer (score 0):

Adrian,

I modified the script as below

```
[...]

send "rm $local_file\r"
expect sftp>

send "exit\r"

set waitval [wait -i $spawn_id]
exit [lindex $waitval 3]
```

I tested a scenario of file not present in our target system and below is the output of it

```
sftp> get /pw/work/outbound/SendBills*.zip /pw/work/inbound/ar/
File "/pw/work/outbound/SendBills*.zip" not found.

sftp> rm /pw/work/outbound/SendBills*.zip
Removing /pw/work/outbound/SendBills*.zip
Couldn't delete file: No such file or directory
```

So i was expecting the spawn expect script to return an exit code other than 0 to my calling .sh script.

I may have forgot to mention that my main script is .sh. Within it, I am calling the expect script which has the above commands that i posted.

Command from my .sh script:

```
if [ "$PSWD" = "Y" ]
then

$PS_APP_HOME/az/scripts/sh/azstmtsftp.exp $USER $PASS $HOST $REMOTE $LOCAL $PORT --   Here is where I am calling the expect script

else 

--This was written in case the third pary goes for SSH keys in future
sftp  $USER@$HOST  <<EOF
get $LOCAL $REMOTE
rm $LOCAL

EOF
fi

RETCODE=$?
```

I was hoping that the $RETCODE will have the error exit code (from my expect script) rather than 0

Based on the return code, i was hoping to plan my further actions.

Regards,
Allen